Processing GET requests on the website Android Java + website
my android application receives data from the site and crashes
What plugins need to be loaded on the site for this code to work? I tried to do it with php in nginx, but there was no success. I think the problem is in HTTP?
Java Code:
public String urlRequest(String str, final Context context) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {



            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(str).openConnection().getInputStream()));

            while (true) {

                String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();

                if (readLine == null) {

                    break;

                }

                sb.append(readLine);

                //sb.append("\n");

            }

            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return sb.toString();

    }



    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        URL url;

        String fetched = null;

        try {

            url = new URL(strings[0]);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                fetched = line;

            }

        }

        catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return fetched;

    }



    @Override

    protected void onPostExecute(String paramString) {

        super.onPostExecute(paramString);

        if (paramString.toString().contains(result())) {

            //FloatingModMenuService.check = true;

            ///context.startService(new Intent(context, FloatingModMenuService.class));

           // Main.start(context);

            Toast.makeText(context, Html.fromHtml(okey()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {

            final AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);


